# In Gemini (5.4), is there a way to create related projects, or sub-projects?

Tags: project, gemini

It seems like we would want to use different project templates depending on which lifecycle phase a system is in.

Answer (score 0):

We use the components field for sub-projects, but that doesn't give you different templates. I couldn't find another way for it so you can utilize different templates.